# Why does this fail to compile?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to get a reference to the tail of a linked list, and here's the code I wrote:

```rust
pub struct ListNode {
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

fn tail(mut head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> &mut Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    while let Some(x) = head.as_mut() {
        head = &mut x.next;
    }
    head
}
```

This fails to compile because it thinks I'm borrowing head as mutable twice. I was able to get to compile by changing it to this:

```rust
fn tail(mut head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> &mut Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    while head.is_some() {
        head = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
    head
}
```

It appears to me that these two functions do the exact same thing, but the first one looks a lot cleaner. Why doesn't it compile? Is there a better way of doing this than what I changed it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a value of the correct reference type, so the `as_mut` is unnecessary.

```
while let Some(x) = head {
    head = &mut x.next;
}
head
```

I can't speak to why your first example doesn't compile, as I'm still no expert in speaking "borrow checker" myself, but my guess is that Rust is just being conservative and assuming that the `head.as_mut()` borrow lasts into the variable `x`, which gets put into `head`, and therefore is a mutable borrow lasting as long as `head` does, whereas when we directly access it as I do above, Rust is smart enough to understand what's really happening.

Comment: The `as_mut` is necessary, it doesn't compile without it. I have an `&mut Option<T>` that I need to turn into an `Option<&mut T>`, which is exactly what `as_mut` is for.

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft [it does compile without it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d1af39f8d5626039687d99f49c12469), unless you'd like to update your question with additional details.

Comment: @pretzelhammer I thought he was referring to the one that I did get to compile. That was a mighty confusing error message that I was getting, never would have guessed that the extraneous `as_mut` was breaking it. Thanks guys!

Comment: This function is just a complicated way of always returning `None` (same for the OP code btw).